# How to query computed distance from coordinates with multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

My app needs to search the nearby users where the users' photos are in other table. Below is my query, but it produces syntax error.

```
TABLE 1 (students)
student_id | name |  latitude  | longitude
----------------------------------------
1          | A    | 34.xxxxxx  | -118.xxxxxx
2          | B    | 34.xxxxxx  | -118.xxxxxx
3          | C    | 34.xxxxxx  | -118.xxxxxx


TABLE 2 (photos)
photo_id   | student_id | photo             | main 
---------------------------------------------------
1          | 1          | apple.jpg         |   1
2          | 1          | orange.jpg        |   0 
3          | 2          | cantaloupe.jpg    |   1
4          | 1          | lemon.jpg         |   0


SET @lat = 34.080318;
SET @lng = -118.239095;
SELECT s.student_id,s.name,s.latitude,s.longitude,p.photo,
    (   ACOS( COS( RADIANS( @lat  ) ) 
            * COS( RADIANS( s.latitude ) )
            * COS( RADIANS( s.longitude ) - RADIANS( @lng ) )
            + SIN( RADIANS( @lat  ) )
            * SIN( RADIANS( s.latitude ) )
        )
    * 3959
    ) AS distance
    FROM students s INNER JOIN photos p ON s.student_id = p.student_id
    HAVING distance < 10
    WHERE p.main=1 AND s.student_id=1
    ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` and `HAVING` are in the wrong order:

```
SELECT s.student_id,s.name,s.latitude,s.longitude,p.photo,
    (   ACOS( COS( RADIANS( @lat  ) ) 
            * COS( RADIANS( s.latitude ) )
            * COS( RADIANS( s.longitude ) - RADIANS( @lng ) )
            + SIN( RADIANS( @lat  ) )
            * SIN( RADIANS( s.latitude ) )
        )
    * 3959
    ) AS distance
    FROM students s INNER JOIN photos p ON s.student_id = p.student_id
    WHERE p.main=1 AND s.student_id=1
    HAVING distance < 10
    ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

By the way, this uses a MySQL extension regarding the `HAVING` clause.  In most databases, you would use a subquery.

Comment: Having tried that before and also got syntax error. This time is `#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '"' Ã  la ligne 13 `

Comment: @user1801605 . . . There are no double quotes in this query.

Comment: My bad, there was a double quote before. Thanks!